# Self referencing Foreign Key SQL Server DeleteAction does nto work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one Table with a self referencing foreign key with DeleteAction set to Cascade, but when Parent is deleted,no children (direct or descendant) does not delete.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use cascade delete on self referencing tables.

Check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/transactsql/thread/972f57fb-f483-4e1b-b3cd-b3116150d842) for possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

**For use delete cascade use following Create table script...**

CREATE 
TABLE

test_child

(
SUB1 INT, [NO] int, FOREIGN KEY ([NO]) REFERENCES Test_parent
ON 
DELETE CASCADE
)

**Check This link for more information:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx

Comment: The example you posted doesn't look like self-referencing table

Comment: He just gave an example of how to set foreign key with TSQL

Comment: @Akshay J - the example is not relevant to the asked question.

Comment: Yes. It's relevant, but I asked this question because the above TSQL does not work as expected.